# Translations that inadvertently work much better in the target language?

Tags: traducción

I have run into a pretty cool phenomenon recently where some passages I have been translating have worked much better in the target language than in the original language. Here is the best example so far:

**Original:**

> If you can't stop thinking about something, it is meant for you. You either pursue your dreams, or they haunt you.
>
> —Mel Robbins

**Translation to Spanish:**

> Si no puedes dejar de pensar en algo, es que está hecho para ti. O persigues tus sueños, o te persiguen.
>
> —Mel Robbins—

Somehow the translation to Spanish created a perfect symmetry in the last sentence that doesn't exist in English. (Spanish uses the word "pursue" for "haunt", so this just works.)

Does anyone have other examples of this? Are there some general principles for how to go looking for more "artistic" ways to translate things so that you can create symmetries like this even if they weren't in the original text, without fundamentally changing the meaning?

Comment: Luke, I also notice another virtue in the translation: while in the first sentence of the original text we have "something" and "it", in the translation the tacit subject would not have worked well for "está hecho para ti" and you needed to reinforce it with the "*que* galicado". Another option could have been: significa que está hecho para ti.

Comment: En algunas situaciones, jugaría con el orden de las palabras ya que en el inglés es mucho más rígido que en el español. Aunque también es cierto que en el inglés se puede invertir el orden de palabras a propósito con fines enfáticos/poéticos...

Comment: jajaja me aparecen todos los translation golfs en la parte de Related. Y si convertimos esta pregunta en uno más? Y si revivimos esa faceta del sitio xd?

Comment: @Gustavson I had to look up the "que galicado", but you're right, your suggested fix improves the translation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know . I think it depends. Sometimes English is more adaptable. I think it has vocabulary which is more adaptable or phrases. Sometimes, I feel Spanish needs 2 or 3 words where English has 1.Example: binge-watch.( ver algo de un tirón/hacer un maratón de..). Also, something is very watchable in English where Spanish seems to lack something(consider,"entretenido). I know,things may work the other way also.

Comment: Ja ja yo pienso que es al revés. Y tenemos buenos equivalentes para gran parte de las palabras en inglés. *binge-watch*, podría traducirse como ‘maratonear’, ‘devorar’, ‘sobredosificar’. *watchable* podría traducirse como ‘apasionante’, ‘interesante’ o incluso en algunos casos ‘dark’ (lo oscuro es lo interesante por lo que ‘esta película es muy dark y por eso me gusta’), etc etc etc etc.

Comment: Vale.Me gusta. y están usadas más en Latina-América que en Espana? Interesante,gracias

Comment: son más de latam, en concreto es lo que se diría en la Argentina. Pero creo que en cualquier lado se entiende perfectamente, ya sea que lo digan o no.